# eclipse: maven dependency search shows only old versions

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, java-5

I'm using Maven to create a spring project. But there are no new versions of spring dependencies when I use mave dependency search (I mean a window that appears when you click button "Add" to add new dependency). Here's my screenshot:
[image: No latest version of spring-cor]

I've opened spring-core, and you can see that the latest version is old. 
In the meantime eclipse maven reposytory window shows the new versions, here's the screenshot:
[image: maven repo window show new versions]

I forsed Maven to Java 8 in the pom-file, because Maven used Java 5. But it hasn't helped. Here's my modified pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.caveofprogramming</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tutorial-5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>     
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Plese tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: What happens when you type **org.springframework** into the dialog, which is the proper groupId?

Comment: @Gimby thank you a lot, it solved my problem!

Comment: It would benefit you to actually think about what the problem actually was, because it revolves around blaming it on the tools while the tools are just doing as they are told.